# Messages sent via the communicate panel error and are undelivered if a cc or bcc is included

Tags: email, messages

EE v2.5.2

Messages sent via the communicate panel work OK and messages are delivered successfully.

But if an address is entered in the cc or bcc field then we get PHP error messages and the mail isn't delivered.

"For security reasons, extra headers for the mail() functionhave been disabled, please contact support for more information.
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1537"

"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/etc/etc/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 412"

Anyone got any ideas what to try?

Answer (score 2):

> "For security reasons, extra headers for the mail() function have been disabled, please contact support for more information"

It sounds like your web host has disabled parts of PHP's mail function. You could try using one of the other mail delivery options (e.g. SMTP), or otherwise I would get in touch with your web host and ask them what they recommend.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug so the first thing to try is update your ExpressionEngine version to the most current version which is 2.7.2